# Visualization of citation network

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am new to mathematica, I want to visualize the citation network using some data, could anyone suggest me which function should I use to visualize the citation network like the following.
[image]

Comment: Have a look at Graph; particularly the options to label vertices and style the graph's edges with colors and thicknesses.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Have a look on this one: Automatic Generation of Academic Citation Graph (Wolfram Language version): https://github.com/lanstonchu/citation-graph

Comment: Could you provide the data associated with the graph you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look into the following Wolfram Research data resources that have citation network examples:

- ["High Energy Physics Theory Network"](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/High-Energy-Physics-Theory-Network)
- ["High Energy Physics Phenomenology Network"](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/High-Energy-Physics-Phenomenology-Network)